# Is using dynamic value on XPATH selenium possible?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to click some element (date) in date picker popup using selenium python, if I define the text it can be clicked. but, when I change it with formatting it not worked and I don't know why.

I already tried this way with formatting string in python way:

```
chosen_date = str(day_date-7)
date_choose = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "// div[contains(text(), '{}')]".format(chosen_date))
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="shopee-react-date-picker__table-cell-wrap"> 
    <div class="shopee-react-date-picker__table-cell selected">6
    </div> 
</div>
```

but, it never worked and always throw an error and stop the script automatically. I'm quite new in using selenium to automate website, is there any possibilities to overcome this error?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

as I can see is there is a space in `// div` section of your selector. There should be not any space:

```
//div[contains(text()
```

the rest is ok.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I already tried your solution but, it still can't work somehow. Is there any alternative to write the code?

Comment: Can you share some piece of your HTML code?

Comment: This is the HTML code:
<div class="shopee-react-date-picker__table-cell-wrap">
<div class="shopee-react-date-picker__table-cell selected">6</div>
</div>